# C Shell Script syntax error "unexpected end of of file"

Tags: shell, shell-script, csh

I am trying to write a c-shell script that checks for number of arguments and echos a string, but I am getting an unexpected end of file syntax error and I don't understand why.

Here is what I tried:

```
if ( $#argv == 0 ) then
echo "Enter one or more args"
else
echo "Entry accepted"
endif
```

Later I tried to output each argument found with this:

```
if ( $#argv == 0 ) then
echo "Enter one or more args"
else
  foreach arg ( $* )
    echo "Found argument $arg"
  end 
endif
```

and got a different syntax error "unexpected token `('"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can get those errors if you ask `bash` to interpret a csh script. The languages are different iin a number of ways.

Comment: OP mention csh tag. I expect he run `csh foo.csh [ blah [ ..]] `

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with comment by [@mark-plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick), OP has to ensure that the script is run by *csh*, e.g., by adding the "hash-bang" line:

```
#!/bin/csh
```

or running the script using the appropriate program:

```
csh ./foo
```

As a general rule, if a script lacks this information it will be run using `/bin/sh`

Further reading:

- [The #! magic, details about the shebang/hash-bang mechanism on various Unix flavours](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)
- [3.16) Why do some scripts start with #! ... ?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html) *Unix - Frequently Asked Questions (3/7)*

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I am using the hash-bang line for this. Thank you

Comment: Without that line, I and (apparently) Mark get exactly the error messages you reported.  With the line, there are none.

Comment: @AndrewWong If you type `/bin/csh ` followed by the file name of the script, do you still get the syntax error messages? It's possible someone has overwritten your csh executable with bash.